# template metaprogramming Ternary value not hitting base case

Tags: c++, templates, struct, ternary-operator, template-meta-programming

I am writing a simple test program using TMP to calculate the Nth fibonacci number. I have already found many ways to do this, but I'm just trying out a bunch of ways to get my understanding better. The way I am having a problem with is this:

```
template<int A>
struct fib
{
    static const bool value = (A<2);
    static const int num = (value?A:(fib<A-1>::num + fib<A-2>::num));
};
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum) instantiating 'fib<-1796>::value'|
```

I have tried substituting many values into the "false" field of the ternary, just to play with it and see what it does. I still do not understand why this does not work. Can anyone help me and tell me why? Thanks.

EDIT: My guess is that the compiler might be evaluating the T/F fields of the ternary before checking to see if the value is true or false, but I'm not sure since that's not how an if statement is supposed to work at all, and these are supposed to roughly emulate if statements

Comment: Being in the wrong branch of the ternary operator does not stop template instantiations.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you, that looks like why it is not compiling. Ill look into std::conditional for better methods.

Answer (score 3):

I must admit that I'm not that experienced concerning template programming. But in OP's case, a simple solution would be template specialization.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int A>
struct fib
{
  static const int num = fib<A-1>::num + fib<A-2>::num;
};

template<>
struct fib<1>
{
  static const int num = 1;
};

template<>
struct fib<2>
{
  static const int num = 1;
};

int main()
{
  fib<10> fib10;
  std::cout << "fib<10>: " << fib10.num << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
fib<10>: 55
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a96fbc9d50851112)</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, I've already made metaprograms to solve this (and one of them was basically the way you're showing here), I was just curious why this particular way would not work.

Comment: @SaswatMishra I believe: as mentioned above, both branches of ternary operator are compiled and hence compiler cannot stop recursion. (This brought me to the idea with specialization.) Btw. I tried `constexpr int fib(int n) { return n > 2 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : 1; }`. If I understood it right it is compile-time computed as well but a bit shorter. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to write this in a more straightforward manner is to use `if constexpr`. Unlike with regular `if` (and with the ternary operator), templates in the not taken branch are not instantiated.

```
template <int n>
struct fib {
   constexpr static int eval() {
      if constexpr (n < 2)
        return n;
      else
        return fib<n-1>::eval() + fib<n-2>::eval();
   }
};
```

Of course once you have `if constexpr` you don't really need templates to make a compile-time function of this type. A `constexpr` non-template function will do just fine. This is just an illustration of the technique.

Answer (score 0):

The first comment on my original post is the correct answer. The author is (n.m.). Template type instantiations are evaluated in both fields of the ternary, while the object instantiation itself is not. To solve this, I will look into std::condiditional or std::enable_if